# TLS and OpenSSL errors

Tags: nyx, ssl

I have just finished setting up a Tor relay and am using `nyx` for monitoring. I am constantly being warned about the following error:

```
Nov 29 20:49:54.000 [warn] TLS error: internal error (in SSL routines:tls13_hkdf_expand:---)
Nov 29 20:50:04.000 [warn] Unhandled OpenSSL errors found at ../src/common/buffers_tls.c:155:
Nov 29 20:50:04.000 [warn] TLS error: internal error (in SSL routines:tls13_hkdf_expand:---)
```

Is that something to be concerned about... and anyway why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same error since upgrade from openssl to version openssl-1.1.1.a-1 on linux arch.
Downgrading openssl to version openssl-1.1.1-1 solved the problem.

Comment: yeah bruh... helped in my case too Kudos!

Comment: Same error with 1.1.1a and Tor 0.3.4.9 on CentOS 7.6.

Answer (score 2):

Due to regression introduced in OpenSSL 1.1.1a. Openssl says fix in next openssl release:
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/7712

Until then, workaround for coping with OpenSSL 1.1.1a added to Tor:
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/28616

Can confirm that Tor 0.3.5.7 no longer issues these errors.
Look for this in the Tor log:

```
[warn] Detected OpenSSL bug 7712: disabling TLS 1.3 on future connections. A fix is expected to appear in OpenSSL 1.1.1b.
```